# How to use Taxonomy Facets together with Apache Solr Multisite Search ?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, search, multi-sites

This regards http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_multisitesearch
I'm trying to enable Multisite Search Facets (based on Taxonomies) for a few sites. The 'normal' multisite facets such as 'filter by site', 'current search' etc appear fine but facets based on Taxonomies do not appear not matter what I do. The facets are enabled and the blocks added to regions, caches cleared etc.

Tested in Drupal Core 6.20 with the latest stable version of Apache Solr & Apache Solr Multisite Search

Has anyone else successfully enabled this functionality?

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: We're your solr facets appearing before adding multisitesearch? The reason i ask is that I have just installed solr (no multisearch) and the facets blocks are not appearing either. Is so, then it might be a plain solr issue.

Comment: Yes the 'single' site facets were appearing :(

Answer (score 1):

A little patch that solve the issue

```
Index: apachesolr_multisitesearch.module
===================================================================
--- apachesolr_multisitesearch.module   (révision 32470)
+++ apachesolr_multisitesearch.module   (copie de travail)
@@ -331,6 +331,10 @@
             return apachesolr_date_facet_block($response, $query, 'apachesolr_multisitesearch', $delta, $delta, t('Filter by post date'));
           case 'hash':
             return apachesolr_facet_block($response, $query, 'apachesolr_multisitesearch', $delta, $delta, t('Filter by site'), 'theme_apachesolr_breadcrumb_hash');
+            
+           //syg on ajoute un retour pours toutes les autres facets
+          default:
+            return apachesolr_facet_block($response, $query, 'apachesolr_multisitesearch', $delta, $delta, t('Filter by %field', array('%field'=> $delta)));
         }
       }
       break;
```